# What is InstallerException and can it be thrown from a hook_install() implementation?

Tags: 8

The documentation for this Exception class is this:

> Base class for exceptions thrown by installer.

By "installer" does it mean any hook_install implementation? Which is what I assume, a counterpart to UpdateException? The [hook_install documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.2.x) makes no mention of this, so my best guess is that it is a part of some plugin ecosystem.

Comment: If you want to prevent a module from being installed, you can use hook_requirements() with the install op. Then you can check the system and prevent installation if e.g. a PHP extension is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not for hook_install(), this exception is for errors during installation of a new drupal site:

*install.core.inc:*

```
function install_drupal($class_loader, $settings = []) {
  ...
  try {
    // Begin the page request. This adds information about the current state of
    // the Drupal installation to the passed-in array.
    install_begin_request($class_loader, $install_state);
    // Based on the installation state, run the remaining tasks for this page
    // request, and collect any output.
    $output = install_run_tasks($install_state);
  }
  catch (InstallerException $e) {
    ...
  }
}
```